# Why we take gravitational acceleration negative even if the body is moving in the direction of the gravity?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, coordinate-systems, conventions

let we throw a ball vertically upward and it comes back to the ground after 6 seconds. So to calculate the initial velocity we use $s=ut+(1/2)gt^2$ 
but we take the value of $g$ negative for the whole motion. Why is that?

Comment: We define up as the positive direction.  Gravity is pointing down throughout the entire motion, so it's negative for the whole problem.

Comment: doesn't it matter in which direction the body is moving?

Comment: Nope. You throw a ball up, or you throw it down, gravity is still going to pull it down to earth.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is the rate of change of velocity with time:

$$ a = \frac{dv}{dt} $$

So the acceleration is negative if the velocity is decreasing.

Assuming we define the upward direction to be positive, the ball starts with a positive velocity $+v$, slows to a halt at the top of its trajectory, then the velocity becomes negative as the ball falls downwards again and ends up at $-v$.

So the velocity decreases from an initial value of $+v$ to zero in the upward flight, then decreases again from zero to $-v$ in the downward flight. Since the velocity is always decreasing the acceleration is always negative.